# Why a new handle is created when calling WS2_32 shutdown?

Tags: sockets, resource-leak

This is really puzzling me, here is a stack trace that shows calling shutdown on my socket has actually ended up creating another handle for a thread, which is causing a handle leak.

```
0x00007ffe0b560064: ntdll!NtCreateEvent+0x0000000000000014
0x00007ffe06cb5ab6: mswsock!MSAFD_SockThreadInitialize+0x000000000000002e
0x00007ffe06cb5a60: mswsock!SockEnterApiSlow+0x000000000000003c
0x00007ffe06cbc591: mswsock!WSPShutdown+0x0000000000000221
0x00007ffe0a3318f2: WS2_32!shutdown+0x0000000000000072
... some other function calls
0x00007ff7cdf7479c: X!thread_start<unsigned int (__cdecl*)(void * __ptr64)>+0x0000000000000050
0x00007ffe0b017974: KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x0000000000000014
0x00007ffe0b52a271: ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x0000000000000021
```

The call is simple shutdown(sock, 1); but why a new handle is created?
I am not calling shutdown twice on the socket, but definitely missing something, am I not?

Comment: Are you certain a new thread has been created?  In the stack trace I see your thread calling `shutdown()`, and eventually that calls to `MSAFD_SockThreadInitialize()`, but it's not clear that `MSAFD_SockThreadInitialize()` is creating a thread (its name notwithstanding)

Comment: Oh right, it is an event for the thread, but what thread? and why does it do that? This is the !htrace output, that shows a handle at this point was created and left open. I understand it is not the actual source code, but to get some rough idea: https://github.com/pustladi/Windows-2000/blob/master/private/net/sockets/winsock2/wsp/msafd/sockproc.c#L2634

Comment: My guess is the calling thread.  I trust that you do call `closesocket()` on the socket after `shutdown()` ?  If not, then you're leaking the socket, and the leaked handle might be a part of that.

Comment: Thanks for your help @JeremyFriesner, this is the call that I could confirm close socket is being executed on:

    iRC = shutdown(sock, 1) ;
    iRC = select(1, &readFds, 0, 0, &timeVal) ;
    iRC = closesocket(sock) ;

Comment: @AmirDashti per the code in that link, `SockEnterApiSlow()` returns a pointer to Thread-Local data, calling `SockThreadInitialize()` only if that TLS data hasn't been initialized yet for the calling thread. And that initialization includes creating a new event object, which is used to signal completion of socket I/Os performed by the calling thread. So, it stands to reason that `shutdown()` is trying to perform I/O using that TLS data, which is why it calls `SockEnterApiSlow()`. When the calling thread terminates and cleans up its TLS data, that event object should get freed as well.

Comment: @AmirDashti are you calling `shutdown()` from the same thread that creates the socket?  I'm guessing not.  Which is not a big deal, that is certainly allowed.  But you are just seeing a minor implementation detail of doing so, that's all.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the comments, after a lot of investigation, it seems the shutdown is being called from another thread than the one created it. The problem is the handle that is being created as a result of that is not being released. Thanks.